# Angular app not working when deploying to firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

Basically I'm just getting endless loading.

my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/my-app",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I built the project, and there is indeed index.html inside my-app folder.

I just don't know where the problem is, maybe routing? I'm using the same router config as I used is local host, didn't change anything when deployed

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the network tab in your browsers developer console while loading the app?

Comment: @jfhr All status 200, even if I'm manually navigate to some page, it's just stay in pending

Comment: @Masksway Do you see any errors in the console.If not then run the build file locally at first and see whether it works fine or not.As well as check whether the dist folder has another sub-folder named my-app or the dist folder just has the index.html and other js files

Comment: @NidhinKumar no errors and no another folder/files

Comment: @Masksway Then try to run the build file locally to see it works fine or not